# inner product - homomorphic encryption library

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want to do a very simple thing:

Given two vectors, I want to encrypt them and do some calculation, then decrypt the result and get the inner product between both vectors.

Can you recommend me some library that can do this thing? Any other material will help me as well.

I found HELIB, but I still dont know if that is the best that I can do. Would you recommend this library? Do you know better ones for my purpose? I want to do it as fast as possible for the biggest vector dimension possible.

I have only basic knowledge in crypto, so I would like use that as black box as much as possible without putting to much effort in the mathematics behind it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *homomorfic encpertyption* is hilarious. Btw, recommendation requests for outside tools/libs/resources are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: [Cross-posted on crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/inner-product-with-homomorphic-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly that with the homomorphic encryption library [Pyfhel](https://pypi.org/project/Pyfhel/) in Python3. Just install it using `pip install Pyfhel` and create a simple demo:

```
from Pyfhel import Pyfhel, PyCtxt

he = Pyfhel()        # Object in charge of all homomorphic operations
he.contextGen(10000) # Choose the maximum size of your values
he.keyGen(10000)     # Generate your private/public key pair

# Now to the encryption/operation/decryption
v1 = [5.34, 3.44, -2.14, 9.13]
v2 = [1, 2.5, -2.1, 3]

p1 = [he.encrypt(val) for val in v1]
p2 = [he.encrypt(val) for val in v2]

pMul = [a*b for a,b in zip(p1, p2)]

pScProd = [pMul[0]+p for p in pMul[1:]

round(he.decrypt(pScProd), 3)
#> 45.824
```

Comment: Note that the most recent versions of `Pyfhel` (3+) use better encoding techniques. Check [Demo_7_ScalarProd.py](https://github.com/ibarrond/Pyfhel/blob/master/examples/Demo_7_ScalarProd.py) for an up-to-date code!